# How to use rspec rails helper methods in a gem -- outside a rails install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, tdd

I have a gem I'm working on that is dependent upon rails to run. Specifically, the gem includes a 'helper' method that uses the 'content_tag' call to build output that will be used in constructing a rails view.

How can I write a helper spec that instantiates enough of the rails infrastructure to be able to use rspec-rails to use the 'helper' prefix to test the code?

Here's an example of what I want:

```
  describe "when this helper is called" do
    it "it works correctly" do
      helper.my_helper_method(data, custom_options = {}).should == "whatever"
    end
  end
```

I'm running rails 3.1 and don't mind making the gem require 3.1 as a minimum rails version.

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f66586bbfacbce4c07f2b9d8d142be1bf6d4e5e/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L92) it seems like you might get away with requiring ActiveSupport and ActionView, then mixing in ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

Comment: Check that - practically speaking, I think once you get the ActionPack gem its dependency chain would take care of everything you need.